# Android Deprecated methods only for old sdk

Tags: java, android, annotations, warnings, deprecated

I'm developing a library with minSdkVersion=9
The lib reacts with the Application lifecycle and registering the callback with: *Application.registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks)*. This method was added since api 14 so for backward-compatibility my lib provide some methods for manually call by the end-developer. For example a method onActivityResumed() that the end developer should call in his Activities onResume().

I would like to annotate this method so only if the end-developer project has minSdkVersion >= 14 this method gives a warning as it is @Deprecated.

Do you know if this is possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The IDE can't show the deprecated warning only if minSdkVersion >= 14, but you can add a annotation at runtime, as you can see here: https://prismoskills.appspot.com/lessons/Super_Java/Dynamically_adding_annotations.jsp